# Expect and Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, except

I'm trying to do an `expect` script with a loop which tries to connect in `ssh` and see if it's possible (Good Password and reachable). I tried to put the result into a variable but only the end of the *stdout* is recorded and not all the *stdout*. How could I do?

```
result=$(
(/usr/bin/expect << EOF
    spawn ssh $username@$ip -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
    set timeout 2
    expect ":"
    send -- "$password\r"
    expect ">"
    send -- "show clock\r"
    expect ">"
EOF
) 2>&1)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean (re: "only the end of the stdout is recorded and not all the stdout")? What exactly is in your output, what do you *expect* to be in your output, and how are you checking? (Often, folks do something like `echo $result` that obscures actual content).

Comment: If I write : 
     echo $result 

Only a part of the last line is showed.

Comment: `declare -p result` is generally a better way to see the actual content of a variable -- lots of ways `echo` can mess things up. If there's a chance of hidden characters messing things up, `printf '%q\n' "$result"` is likewise an improvement. But if you *are* going to use `echo`, at least avoid leaving out your quotes: `echo "$result"`, not `echo $result`.

Comment: You used the tag except for your question which is not the same as expect.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to automate sending a command to another server using `ssh`:

- Generate an `ssh` key, instead of using passwords:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
  ```
- Copy it to the server:

  ```
  ssh-copy-id id@server
  ```

Now you don't need to worry about the password. `ssh` keys act as passwords, and generally are *much* more secure. See these ([SSH login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html), [Why is using SSH key more secure than using passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/why-is-using-ssh-key-more-secure-than-using-passwords)) for more information about `ssh` keys.

Then you can just use this command - no `expect` needed, because you won't be asked for a password. It'll use your `ssh` key. Mine is located at `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. So:

```
ssh id@server -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa "show clock;"
```

- `-i` stands for the *identity file*, i.e., your `ssh` key file.

will send a command to the SSH server.

Altogether now:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
ssh-copy-id id@server
ssh id@server -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa "show clock;"
```

Three commands, and you've done it!

Comment: And since `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the (a?) default, you don't need the `-i` argument. `ssh id@server show clock`.

Comment: @chepner That works, but if you're like me you have many `ssh` keys for different servers. I've included the `-i` flag so it's clear that you can also choose which `ssh` file to use in that command.

Answer (score 0):

## Calling to expectscript from shell script:

```
expect "/copySSHKey.exp <machine> <password> </.ssh/id_rsa.pub path>"
```

## Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set machine [lrange $argv 0 0]
set ip [lrange $argv 1 1]
set pass [lrange $argv 2 2]
set path [lrange $argv 3 3]

set timeout -1
spawn ssh-keygen -R ${machine}
spawn ssh-copy-id -i ${path} root@${machine}

match_max 100000

expect {

   sleep 10

   "password" {
            send -- "$pass\r"
            send -- "\r"
            sleep 1
            send_user " SSH key copied to $machine\n"
    }

    "$machine's" {
            send_user " SSH key copied to $machine\n"
    }

    "password:*" {
            send -- "$pass\r"
            send -- "\r"
            sleep 1
            send_user " SSH key copied to $machine\n"
    }

    "machine" {
            sleep 1
            send_user " SSH key copied to $machine\n"
    }
}

interact
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using double quotes (") to capture the subshell's output. Maybe you're losing data because of parsing issues:

```
result="$( ... )"
```

Comment: Not actually needed on an assignment -- this is a context where string-splitting and glob expansion is disabled. You can easily test this yourself: `var=$(printf '%s\n' hello cruel world '*'); declare -p var`, and note that the newlines are still there (not replaced with spaces as they would be if string-splitting with a default IFS had taken place), and so is the asterisk (not replaced with a list of files in the current working directory).